# Cart Price rule is not working if the product is available in multiple categories Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

In my magento we are using Mexbs Bunlde Discount extension to create cart price rules.

i created one rule like - A product from X category + B product form Y category + C product from Z category for 10$

[image]

Now i added three products from three categories and applying the cart price rule, its not working. when i am checking the products 3rd product is present in both categories 6 and 4. If i remove that product from category 6 then coupon is applying fine.

In this case how we can create a rule or is any other way to achive this?

Thanks